# Graphing actual months in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, date, microsoft-excel-365

I have been looking on the forum to the best of my ability and I can't find the exact answer to my question. It seems trivial though so if I have missed it I do apologize.

I have a graph were I am trying to plot cost vs months. I figured out how to go about doing the text date to numeric date conversion.While excel treats the dates correctly and the x axis is not graphing information incorrectly, I cannot seem to get it to graph information usefully.

Because the x axis can only be divided into even or logarithmic scales, there is no way to account for the fact that all months have differing amounts of days. Therefore my x axis scale makes the chart appear as though none of the y axis points correspond to the x axis points.

Is there a way in which I could round the input data in order to make the chart appear as one would imagine it should? Where all of the data points fall onto a line which represents the beginning of a month? Maybe adding an extra column which takes the data and truncates it somehow? I have been playing with the ROUND function but to no avail currently.

Thank you ahead of time for taking some time to read this!

[Graph of cost vs. exact date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlaWK.png)

Comment: You mean to say Dates in order of Months in Ascending order !!

Comment: Try formatting your axis and setting the minor units to 1 month

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean @RajeshS.

Comment: Also I am asking how exactly to set my axis settings to one month exactly @cybernetic.nomad. I can't seem to find a good way to do so that accounts for the fact that all months are not equal in length.